# ARM reverse engineering ROM dump

Tags: c, pointers, arm, reverse, rom

I ve old embedded system, with ARM cpu core, I dumped ROM, extracted with binwalk, and loaded on IDA pro.
I found in some routine routine, BX not with LR but with general purpose register(R2, R3 etc..)in pseudo code became like some this "memory[0xCC1232](a3, v4)" it is example. I thought that it is like ARM compiler build C pointer function. could it be?
Anyway my main question is this, how can I found this subroutine (memoryx..)with only rom dump?because the address is ram address, so without ram dump, can't I find reference to this subroutine?I thought to find routine that write value to this particular address, but it is almost impossible
thank you

Comment: I think this is a very interesting question. Could you add more of the pseudo code to the question? And could you also add what you think is the memory layout? It would help people get a better overall picture and increase the chances for a helpful answer.

Comment: RAM dump? Assuming that you are able to do that, it would be a snapshot of a very specific (and ethereal) momment, which may be unique and totally different after 1msec.

Comment: @Jose you are wrong, because it is ram address that has like value pointer to function, it isn t "data" section, that change, It is same value for all time that embedded system is on

Comment: @Codo I ve some idea what is memory layout of the ram and rom in address space.
Pseudo code is somethig like this "MEMORY[0xCC9B9C]()", where 0xCC9B9C is ram address, that contain the value of the entry point subroutine. I mean the value where BX jump..

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the compiler settings and what core is being targetted, bx without lr is very common, if not required as the older cores pop (ldmia usually) of lr does not work for switching between arm and thumb modes so the compilers will generate pop to like r3 then bx r3.

```
extern unsigned int more_fun ( void );
unsigned int fun ( void )
{
    return(more_fun()+1);
}

00000000 <fun>:
   0:   b510        push    {r4, lr}
   2:   f7ff fffe   bl  0 <more_fun>
   6:   3001        adds    r0, #1
   8:   bc10        pop {r4}
   a:   bc02        pop {r1}
   c:   4708        bx  r1
   e:   46c0        nop         ; (mov r8, r8)

vs

00000000 <fun>:
   0:   b508        push    {r3, lr}
   2:   f7ff fffe   bl  0 <more_fun>
   6:   3001        adds    r0, #1
   8:   bd08        pop {r3, pc}
   a:   bf00        nop
```

r4 vs r3 as the dummy register doesn't matter here; it is interesting that the compiler does this, but they are just being used to make the stack aligned, not to preserve the register.

This is thumb mode of course, arm mode:

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
   4:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <more_fun>
   8:   e8bd4010    pop {r4, lr}
   c:   e2800001    add r0, r0, #1
  10:   e12fff1e    bx  lr
```

You would expect to see lr used with a bx lr.

Or this for newer, but gcc at least defaults to thumb mode and you have to force it to generate arm code like this:

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
   4:   ebfffffe    bl  0 <more_fun>
   8:   e2800001    add r0, r0, #1
   c:   e8bd8010    pop {r4, pc}
```

As far as finding what is in ram you have to do more work and it might not be possible. If this is an embedded system and everything is in non-volatile memory (flash/rom/etc) then at some point if code is in ram then it is copied or decompressed or other into ram before being branched to. On the other hand you may have disassembled some code that is there to be able to call code in ram but that code in ram may come from a download, basically some external source that is not ultimately on board/chip.  Like a bootloader that has code to download a program over the uart and then branch to it, doesn't mean that code is used normally and certainly means you can't predict or know what that code is going to be, much less find it and disassemble it.

A bx of not lr can be used by hand to launch into such code if I download into 0x20000000 and somehow know this is thumb code not arm then I need to orr the address with a 1 in some way then bx to that, sometimes you do that with a register, sometimes not.

You will also see a bx used by the linker to patch up something far away or for changing modes:

```
unsigned int more_fun ( void )
{
    return(3);
}
```

The linker adds the trampoline for you:

```
00000000 <fun>:
   0:   e92d4010    push    {r4, lr}
   4:   eb000003    bl  18 <__more_fun_from_arm>
   8:   e8bd4010    pop {r4, lr}
   c:   e2800001    add r0, r0, #1
  10:   e12fff1e    bx  lr

00000014 <more_fun>:
  14:   2003        movs    r0, #3
  16:   4770        bx  lr

00000018 <__more_fun_from_arm>:
  18:   e59fc000    ldr r12, [pc]   ; 20 <__more_fun_from_arm+0x8>
  1c:   e12fff1c    bx  r12
  20:   00000015    andeq   r0, r0, r5, lsl r0
  24:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
```

and in this case used r12.

Comment: thank you.
the cose of my 'BX R2' it isn t thumb mode, it is arm940 core, I found almost nothing in thumb mode. I think that only way is to find routine that do store to this address and set value of the entry point of this routine, but without entry point of the all ROM dump, I think is almost impossible find this kind of routine. It s surely in ROM dump, but recognizing it, is hard..I tried but I ven' t more ideas

Comment: arm920 not arm940

Comment: if you look at the data at an aligned word level if a lot of the words start with 0xE a seemingly high percentage that is probably arm code/instructions.  thumb you look halfword aligned and I used to say there were a lot of 0x6s and 0x7s but its not as easy to pick out as arm instructions.

Comment: one could/would argue the beginning of the rom would be the exception table for the arm, but that isnt always the case depends on the chip and other factors.  the good thing about arm only is you dont have to disassemble in execution order you can just walk through a binary in address order understanding some percentage of it is data and the disassembly will be nonsense,  but with that you can maybe find a chunk of instructions in a row that are branching nearby and that might be the vector/exception table.

Answer (score 0):

In general case, it is not possible to determine actual jump address without disassembling and analysing code. However, several tips and tricks are possible.

1. Very often part of ROM is copied to RAM at very early startup. Try to find that copy routine in initialisation. If you're lucky, you'll be able initial contents of RAM location you're interested in. And if you're very lucky, that location is not rewritten in runtime, and it will be actual data. (See below)
2. Try to disassemble portion of code before. In most cases address is fetched from some table in ROM then stored in local variable, and address of that table is there.
3. In most cases subroutine code bodies reside at start of ROM back to back, starting with entry point and ended with `BX LR`. You can find all or most subroutine entry points just by scanning through ROM, suspecting that entry point to next subroutine is next to 'BX LR' of previous. To determine if specific subroutine is called indirectly try to search if its plain address exist somewhere in ROM, or it is loaded with 'MOVW'+'MOVT' pair. This give you idea where it may be used.
4. In several cases subroutine address is passed as a parameter to subroutine call. So try to search if any caller is referring to some address in code.
5. There could be procedure tables, looking like long runs of words pointing to ROM code area (possibly interleaved with nulls). Try to find them and determine which one could be used in your case.

An example RAM initialisation code taken from GNAT's runtime:

```
        movw    r0,#:lower16:__data_start ; __data_start points to RAM
        movt    r0,#:upper16:__data_start ; (often it is start of RAM)
        movw    r1,#:lower16:__data_words
        movw    r2,#:lower16:__data_load  ; __data_load points to ROM
        movt    r2,#:upper16:__data_load  ; right after code and readonly data
        cbz     r1,1f
0:      ldr     r4,[r2],#4
        str     r4,[r0],#4
        subs    r1,r1,#1
        bne     0b
1:
```

Comment: thank you for answer.
1 I tried to do this, because I think all content of the rom is copied in ram, and I tried to find starter routine that initialize ram value like that.
But I found nothing, I think because I ven t entry point (main function), I ve routine that use argument that I don t know waht is the value, so it is analysis loop, you mean..maybe I didn t say clear enough.
2 I don t think so, because with IDA if it is so, I can try reference to address with X key command, but nothing, I ven t reference to this address

Comment: 1. Did you find exception vector table? It could be at address 0 and its 0th (1st in Cortex) element points to first instruction to be executed.

Comment: I think vector table is at address 0, but function it isn t handler of exception.
I think, that this address ram is initialized with function address during bootloader..

Comment: Initial vector table should be in ROM, otherwise CPU itself or bootloader coudn't know how to start the code.

Comment: yes it is  address 0 of my ROM dump, anyway, it don t help me to figure out. Maybe without full RAM dump, or debugging mode of cpu (like jtag..)it is hard find solution..I don t know, I ven't ideas..routine is in ROM dump but I don t know what is that called from this branch...